# Get propertyinfo from lambda expression, but fails with int

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, expression-trees

What is the best way to get to all the PropertyInfo of items in a lambda expression.

i want to set a filter on a xml field in a sql database.

```
var FilterBase = new FilterBase<SimpleItemSubObject>()
                    .SetSimpleFilter(x => x.ID, 123)
                    .SetSimpleFilter(x => x.Test.Name, "demo3");
```

in de analyser, i'm able to get the propertyinfo for the Name property.

```
internal IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetExpressionList()
{
    return GetPropertyListfor(lambda.Body as MemberExpression);
}

private IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetPropertyListfor(MemberExpression body)
{
    var result = new List<PropertyInfo>();
    if (body != null && body.Expression != null)
    {
        result.AddRange(GetPropertyListfor(body.Expression as MemberExpression));
        result.Add((body as MemberExpression).Member as PropertyInfo);
    }

    return result;
}
```

this will return the propertyinfo if it's a string property. but in case of a int the analyser fails because lambda has added a convert function.

```
{x => Convert(x.ID)}
```

It added a convert function.

so what is the best method of getting the propertyinfo in this case for the x.ID. and how do i prevent the use of the convert function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that compiler adds `Convert` expression indicates that you are using non generic lambda expression with `object` return type. Something like this:

```
public class FilterBase<T>
{
    public FilterBase<T> SetSimpleFilter(Expression<Func<T, object>> selector, object value)
    {
        // ...
        return this;
    }
}
```

One way to resolve the issue is to make the method generic (similar to LINQ `OrderBy`):

```
public FilterBase<T> SetSimpleFilter<V>(Expression<Func<T, V>> selector, V value)
```

so there will not be `Convert` anymore.

Another way is to keep the method as is, and strip the first `Convert` if any:

```
internal IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetExpressionList()
{
    var body = lambda.Body;
    if (body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
        body = ((UnaryExpression)body).Operand;
    return GetPropertyListfor(body as MemberExpression);
}
```

Comment: thanks. for your answer. I stripped the convert as you said. But thanks for the info about the reason why convert is added.